# OpenGL update VBO vertices bufferSubData

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, vertices, vao

I am new to openGL and I've got a code like this learning from the tutorial

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height);

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
                                 "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
                                 "void main()\n"
                                 "{\n"
                                 "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
                                 "}\0";
const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
                                   "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
                                   "void main()\n"
                                   "{\n"
                                   "   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
                                   "}\n\0";

int main() {

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);


    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }



    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, nullptr, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, nullptr, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, nullptr, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);


    float vertices[] = {
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,  // top right
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // bottom right
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f   // top left
    };

    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), nullptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


    glBindVertexArray(0);



    // render loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    
        processInput(window);

  
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO); 
        vertices[0] += 0.1f;
        vertices[1] += 0.1f;
        vertices[2] += 0.1f;

        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), &vertices);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

 
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }


    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);


    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}


void processInput(GLFWwindow *window) {
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height) {
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

As you noticed in render loop I am trying to change the vertices value e.g. move my drawn triangle, while not creating a new VBO but updating its data...
I've read that glBuferSubData is for updating VBO's sub data without creating a new one, and I've done that like this

```
 while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        processInput(window);

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        vertices[0] += 0.1f;
        vertices[1] += 0.1f;
        vertices[2] += 0.1f;

        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), &vertices);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

I think I am doing something wrong as the triangle does not move... How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml) updates a subset of a buffer object's data store of the buffer which is currently bound to the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` target. The array buffer binding is a global state. As soon as you call `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` the binding of the `VBO` buffer is lost.
Either skip `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` or bind the buffer just before calling `glBufferSubData`:

```cpp
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), &vertices);
```

Comment: removing the unbind of VBO object worked for me, though I thought as VAO is saving the state of an array of the object, the VBO will be bound automatically as VAO binds....
then what's the purpose of binding VAO ? Just to bind the state of the object e.g. "settings" of drawing?

Comment: @HrantNurijanyan No the VAO doesn't bind the VBO. Why should it? Each attribute may refer to a different buffer object. Which one should be bound? The VAO only knows which attribute uses which buffer object. But binding the VAO is not a shortcut for binding VBOs. As I mentioned in the answer *"The array buffer binding is a global state."*